# Existence of differentiable function if partial derivatives are equal

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be differentiable and $D_1f(x,y)=D_2f(x,y),~ \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$. 
My problem is to show that there is a differentiable function

$\Phi: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ so that $f(x,y)= \Phi(x+y),~ \forall x,y \in \mathbb R$.

I'm afraid I have no clue how to start here or which theorem might help me out there so I would be pleased about any help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The fundamental theorem of calculus may be useful.  I would also come up with some examples/counterexamples. Pick some simple f's (polynomials) and see how it works.

Comment: Perhaps you should think about the level curves of $f$. Review what you know about the gradient and the level curves.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Define the function $g : \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}$ by 
$$
g(x,y) = f(x-y,y).
$$
Then using the properties of $f$, you should find that $D_y g(x,y) = 0$ for every $(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2$. In particular, for any fixed $x \in \Bbb{R}$, $g(x,y_1) = g(x,y_2)$, since the map $y \mapsto g(x,y)$ has zero derivative and is hence constant. In particular, for every $(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2$
$$
g(x+y, x+y) = g(x+y,y).
$$
Now, put this last equality in terms of $f$.

Comment: Thanks for answering! What I don't quite get - what is my function $\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ then? I just see $\mathbb R^2$ as a domain

Comment: If there is such a function $\Phi : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ such that $f(x,y) = \Phi(x+y)$ then you can see immediately that $f(x,0) = f(0,x) = \Phi(x)$. So define $\Phi(x) = f(0,x)$. Now $\Phi(x+y) = f(0,x+y)$ so you need to be able to conclude that $f(x,y) = f(0,x+y)$.. but this is where the hint comes in.